# Discord JS - Counting boosts

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have one counter left to create. And for this one I don't really know which direction to take.
I believe counting the number of members with the boost role will be wrong as members can have boosted the server twice.

```
module.exports = async(client) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('912706237806829598');


    setInterval(async () => {
        const boostCount = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter(????????).size;
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('960832075349499925');
        channel.setName(`╭・Boosts: ${boostCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Updating Boost Count');
        console.log(boostCount);
     }, 600000);
}
```

I don't know if I get achieve this by putting something inside filter. Looking at the members is probably not correct as well.
Really need some assistance for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of [`guild.premiumSubscriptionCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=premiumSubscriptionCount) would help you out. It will count all the boosts in total including double boosts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thought it were gonna be more complex. Got to get my Google skills improved.

Comment: No problem, haha. Took some time for me to find as well